# Smarty in prestashop .tpl, how to print only the value, not the full array

Tags: php, arrays, smarty, prestashop

I wish to print only the value "data" of this result :

```
$ZC_HEALTHBAND_DATA Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = Array (1)
  0 => Array (3)
    id => "3"
    option => "ZC_HEALTHBAND_DATA"
    data => "<table width="100%"><tr><td></td><td ..."
->nocache = false
->scope = "/..."
```

I tried with {$ZC_HEALTHBAND_DATA|@print_r} but that's print both the data and the array ...

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 3 [option] => ZC_HEALTHBAND_DATA [data] =>
<table width="100%"><tr><td></td><td ...
)) 1
```

I just want to print :

```
<table width="100%"><tr><td></td><td ...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a two dimensional array:

```
{$ZC_HEALTHBAND_DATA[0].data}
```